# Is it possible to change fieldset title if collapsed with #states

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to use #states in form api to change the title of a fieldset based on his collapsed states.

so far here's my code :

```
$form['advanced'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Advanced search'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('search-advanced', 'clearfix')),
  '#states' => array(
    '#title' => array(
      array('fieldset#edit-advanced' => array('#collapsed' => 'Hide advanced search')),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I've tried different things, but without success.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've never been able to get states to work with fieldsets; there's an unresolved issue on D.o about it but I can't find at the moment

Comment: @Clive There is a chain of duplicates and related that starts with [this report](http://drupal.org/node/777478). And [this one](http://drupal.org/node/1099132) seems to be exactly about OPs problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that there were some issues with #states and fieldsets, such as [#states can't hide/show fieldsets](https://drupal.org/node/767212), but in your case the code doesn't work because #title is not an handled state, and #collapsed is not a handled state for the remote condition.

The list of the implemented states is given in [drupal_process_states()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7):

- enabled
- disabled
- required
- optional
- visible
- invisible
- checked
- unchecked
- expanded
- collapsed

The states used for the remote conditions are the following:

- empty
- filled
- checked
- unchecked
- expanded
- collapsed
- value

It would also be hard to implement that, as the state needs to be boolean, and the remove condition says the value of the state for the other form field.

For example, if *foo* is a select list, the state for a form field could be the following one.

```
'#states' => array(
  // Show the settings if 'bar' has been selected for 'foo'.
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="foo"]' => array('value' => 'bar'),
  ),
),
```

This state would make the form field visible when the value selected from the list is *bar*.